# How do I alias a rails route with an id?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have these routes:

```
get '/welcome', to: redirect('/welcome/1')
get 'welcome/:id' => 'users#welcome'
```

The redirect route does a 301 to /welcome/1.

Instead of doing a redirect I'd like it to just execute users#welcome with an id of 1.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need:

```
get 'welcome', to: 'users#welcome', defaults: { id: 1 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can give pathname to the route and pass the id as parameter like this.

```
get 'welcome/:id' => 'users#welcome', as: :welcome
```

and pass the id as parameter like this

```
<%= link_to 'Button', welcome_path(id) %>
```